# Sitecore content structure for FAQ items

Tags: sitecore-client

There is one interesting requirement that I am trying to solve. Need input from Sitecore developers

We have to show FAQ questions lists on brands, industries, and techniques pages. So requirement is that::

1. Content Editor can select brands, industries, and techniques for each question
2. When populating on a brand/industry/technique page.

   a. Questions can be featured or normal. Featured questions gets elevated to the top.

   ```
     i.    Content editors want to order the featured questions
   ```

   b.  Featured does not mean featured on ALL brand, industry, and technique pages.

   ```
    i. A question can be featured for Nike (brand), but not featured on Adidas brand.
   ii. A question can be featured for Nike (brand), but not featured on technique page.
   ```

What are the best ways to create a Sitecore Content structure for this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I missed some of your requirements but for me it looks like:

```
- Brands
--- Brand A
--- Brand B
--- Brand C

- Industries
--- Industry A
--- Industry B
--- Industry C

- Techniques
--- Technique A
--- Technique B
--- Technique C
```

Every product have multilist fields for brands, industries and techniques.

```
- Product A (Brand B, Brand C)
- Product B (Brand D, Brand Y)
```

Every brand have multilist field for featured products - here authors can arrange featured products in that given brand.

```
Brand A - Featured Products: (Product 1, Product N)
```

When you search for products for brand, you first check featured on the brand itself and then do another search on products with this brand selected.

Answer (score 0):

surendras,

As per my understanding find below some inputs:

Brand Template
  -Title
  -Description

Industries Template
  -Title
  -Description

Techniques Template
  -Title
  -Description

FAQ Template
  -Title
  -Description
  -Title
  -Tags (Which will show tags from Brands/Industries/Techniques)
  -IsFeatured
  -SortOrder
  -IsActive

When Brands/Industries/Techniques page being loaded then use Meta data of page to search the items in FAQ source to find the
related FAQ Questions and apply the sorting using LINQ in the back-end code.